# iPhone 4s speakers stopped working

Tags: iphone, audio, speakers

During a FaceTime call I suddenly had no sound.  It took me a while to realize it wasn't just on FaceTime, but no ringer, no music, no keyboard clicks.  It does not say headset when I turn volume up so it doesn't seem to be stuck in headset mode although I do get sound that way and I can hear through the receiver, just not speakers.

Comment: Did your headset plug got stuck. Plug it in and wiggle it out. Do you see the headset activated when you plug them in?

Comment: Have you turned the phone off and back on again since this happened? There's a tiny possibility that an audio service running on the phone failed and didn't recover, but could recover with a power-cycle.